# Iterating over checkboxes to retrieve value of checked ones

Tags: jquery

I have the following fiddle in jquery :

```
 var checks = $('input[name= "ScheduleCharge[hspecialty][]"]:checked');
 $(checks).each(function(){ 
     alert($(this).value()); 
 });
```

This just refreshes the page . If I replace `$(this).value()` with `1` , `1` is alerted correct number of times as per the number of checkboxes. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `val()` instead of `value()` as value() is not defined by jquery and error would be causing refresh of page.

```
var checks = $('input[name= "ScheduleCharge[hspecialty][]"]:checked');
$(checks).each(function(){ 
    alert($(this).val()) ; 
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `$(this)` is a **jQuery Object** and value is not valid property for it

Use `.val()` instead

```
alert($(this).val()) ;  $(this)  jQuery Object
```

If you want to use the **value property** use the **DOM object**

```
alert( this.value ) ;   this DOM Object
```